# How do I write a C program that can find the division, and subtraction of n numbers?

Tags: c

I am trying to write a basic calculator program using if else statements but there is a problem with it. The addition and multiplication functions are working but subtraction and division functions are not.
How do I write a C program that can find the subtraction and division of n numbers?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int n, m, i, d;
float sum;
printf("Enter the number what you want to calculate\n");
printf("1.) Addition\n2.) subtraction\n3.) multiplication\n4.) Division\n");
scanf("%d", &n);
if (n == 1) {
printf("\nyou select addition\n");
printf("enter how many number you want to add\n");
scanf("%d", &m);
sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
printf("Enter number%d: ", i + 1);
scanf("%d", &d);
sum += d;
}
printf("your answer is %f", sum);
}
else if (n == 2) {
printf("\nyou select Subtraction\n");
printf("enter how many number you want to Subtract\n");
scanf("%d", &m);
sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
printf("Enter number%d: ", i + 1);
scanf("%d", &d);
sum -= d;
}
printf("your answer is %f", sum);
}
else if (n == 3) {
printf("\nyou select Multiplication\n");
printf("enter how many number you want to Multiply\n");
scanf("%d", &m);
sum = 1;
for (i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
printf("Enter number%d: ", i + 1);
scanf("%d", &d);
sum = sum * d;
}
printf("your answer is %f", sum);
}
else if (n == 4) {
printf("\nyou select Division\n");
 printf("enter how many number you want to divide\n");
scanf("%d", &m);
sum = 1;
for (i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
printf("Enter number%d: ", i + 1);
scanf("%d", &d);
sum /= d;
}
printf("your answer is %f", sum);
}
else
printf("you Enter wrong number");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to indent its code part. Code lines must start with at least four space. Thanks. Then read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). But StackOverflow is not a *do-my-homework* service (so your question is off-topic), and C is not the same as C++

Comment: Please just use `if (n == 1)` and so on, `if (n > 0 && n < 2)` reads like a cruel joke. Or consider a `switch(n)`.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. I think you're just struggling with initial values for `sum` and `sum2`.

Leave `sum` for addition/subtraction (needs to be initialised to 0) and leave `sum2` for multiplication/division (needs to be initialised to 1.)

```
float sum = 0;
float sum2 = 1.;
```

Then addition becomes

```
sum += numbers[i]
```

subtraction becomes

```
sum -= numbers[i]
```

multiplication becomes

```
sum2 *= numbers[i]
```

and division becomes

```
sum2 /= numbers[i]
```

And make sure you get your order right for `printf`, `scanf` and the maths operation.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few bugs in your program:

- `sum2` is never initialized
- The uninitialized `sum2` is printed in the subtraction part
- Since `sum` is initialized to zero so this `sum = sum * numbers[i];` will always result in zero
- Since `sum` is initialized to zero so this `sum /= numbers[i];` will always result in zero
- There is missing an `else` before the `if` in the subtraction block

Then there are room for some imprrovements:

- Use `==` in your `if` statements
- Don't save the input in an array that you never use
- Use a single `sum` that you initialize when the operation is known

Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n, m, i, d;
    float sum;
    printf("Enter the number what you want to calculate\n");
    printf("1.) Addition\n2.) subtraction\n3.) multiplication\n4.) Division\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    if (n == 1) {
        printf("\nyou select addition\n");
        printf("enter how many number you want to add\n");
        scanf("%d", &m);
        sum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
            printf("Enter number%d: ", i + 1);
            scanf("%d", &d);
            sum += d;
        }
        printf("your answer is %f", sum);
    }
    else if (n == 2) {
        printf("\nyou select Subtraction\n");
        printf("enter how many number you want to Subtract\n");
        scanf("%d", &m);
        sum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
            printf("Enter number%d: ", i + 1);
            scanf("%d", &d);
            sum -= d;
        }
        printf("your answer is %f", sum);
    }
    else if (n == 3) {
        printf("\nyou select Multiplication\n");
        printf("enter how many number you want to Multiply\n");
        scanf("%d", &m);
        sum = 1;
        for (i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
            printf("Enter number%d: ", i + 1);
            scanf("%d", &d);
            sum = sum * d;
        }
        printf("your answer is %f", sum);
    }
    else if (n == 4) {
        printf("\nyou select Division\n");
        printf("enter how many number you want to divide\n");
        scanf("%d", &m);
        sum = 1;
        for (i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
            printf("Enter number%d: ", i + 1);
            scanf("%d", &d);
            sum /= d;
        }
        printf("your answer is %f", sum);
    }
    else
        printf("you Enter wrong number");

    return 0;
}
```

BTW: Whenever you do `scanf` you should check that the return value is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Does it work on you?

Comment: @PawanPaudel I have only done a few test and they are fine: Example: `Enter the number what you want to calculate
1.) Addition
2.) subtraction
3.) multiplication
4.) Division
3

you select Multiplication
enter how many number you want to Multiply
2
Enter number1: 3
Enter number2: 4
your answer is 12.000000`

Comment: But i don't think it work on divide because it divide 1 first then other. So it will be the wrong

Comment: @PawanPaudel For divide it does: `1/n1/n2/n3...` What do you expect it to do?

Comment: @PawanPaudel Divived example: `Enter the number what you want to calculate
1.) Addition
2.) subtraction
3.) multiplication
4.) Division
4

you select Division
enter how many number you want to divide
2
Enter number1: 2
Enter number2: 4
your answer is 0.125000`

Comment: It is not working more than 2 numbers in subtraction and divide.

Comment: @PawanPaudel I don't see any problem with more than 2 numbers. Example `Enter the number what you want to calculate
1.) Addition
2.) subtraction
3.) multiplication
4.) Division
2

you select Subtraction
enter how many number you want to Subtract
4
Enter number1: 1
Enter number2: 2
Enter number3: 3
Enter number4: 4
your answer is -10.000000`

Comment: Do you think that's a right answer?  Enter the number what you want to calculate
1.) Addition
2.) subtraction
3.) multiplication
4.) Division
2
you select Subtraction
enter how many number you want to Subtract
4
Enter number1: 10
Enter number2: 4
Enter number3: 2
Enter number4: 3
your answer is -19.000000
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 45.041 s
Press any key to continue. I want like calculator 10-4-2-3=1 answer

Comment: @PawanPaudel If that's what you want you can update the code using a few extra statements. Tip: Don't initialize sum but `scanf` it :-)